# Need help changing from Trane thermostat to Honeywell T9

Tags: thermostat

I currently have Trane thermostat (TH8320U1040) and trying to change it with Honeywell T9 thermostat.

On Trane I currently have following terminals connected:

Wire Color  -  Terminal Name

Orange      -  Y2

Black       -  W2

Red         -  R (R & RC jumped)

White       -  W1

Yellow      -  Y

Green       -  G

Blue        -  B

Honeywell-T9 has following terminals:

S S Y Y2 G C U U A O/B W2 E W K R Rc

I am confused about B and W1 in current Trane.

Should “B in Trane” connect to “C in T9”?

Should “W1 in Trane” connect to “ W in T9”?

Thanks for your help!

Vasan

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler please?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I couldn't figure how to attach the picture here. Hence I added link to my pictures above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: We'll need pictures of the wiring at the *air-handler/furnace* end in order to be able to give a surefire answer to this

Comment: What do the two yellow wires in the bottom left of your picture run off to?

Comment: They go to condensation pump right outside the HVAC unit:    

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xaUCncjmHGfXKHpqi3QkVRWDDVLwtO9p/view?usp=drivesdk          

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZRC30Pmp-Gygnds1cMEUhojjSMKW8j14/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Can you get us a better shot of the cable that enters your HVAC-unit picture at the bottom-center please? Also, where does the two-wire cable that exits that picture at the bottom center go? A humidifier perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have captured few pictures of the bottom-center cable in the unit. Pair of black wires exiting at the bottom are going to EZ-trap. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n9J-mvmSocUTo7YzulrKB7CF_z7cEjvt/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Alright -- can you tell me where the two two-wire thermostat cables exiting off to the left go now that we have the EZ-trap figured out?

Comment: There are 3 brown cables coming out of HVAC. I will call them B1, B2 and B3. 


Two of those cables are going to a small Trane control unit that says “AUTOMATIC MODE” , which is attached to top-left part of HVAC unit. Attached pictures. That Trane Control has 3 wires attached. 


- B1 from HVAC, with red/white wires, is connected to Left port of Trane Control


- B2 from HVAC, with red/white wires, is connected to Right port of Trane Control


- Middle port from Trane control is going to Humidifier. 


- B3 from HVAC, with 5 wires, is going to A/C compressor located outside.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113432/discussion-on-question-by-vasan-need-help-changing-from-trane-thermostat-to-hone).

Comment: Please include photos by editing your question and using the upload picture link. External photos frequently have their links go bad making the question unusable by future visitors. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @Vasan -- can you post a photo of the wiring diagram for your air-handler/furnace please?

Comment: Not sure if this is correct. I found this on the inside of HVAC door. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wiqu9hMTUBYTJygZQBSV6fQ9qqxroBFT/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Hello ThreePhaseEel, does the attached wiring diagram help? Looking forward to your suggestion. Thanks!